# Can I combine two shear-stresses acting on one plane?

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

For example, I have an axial force and a torsion force applied on a rock socket installed in bedrock. So, the socket surface will have two shear stress generated, one in axial direction, and the other in radial direction. If I want to design this, what is the maximum I should use?

Can I combine the two stresses by triangle rule, or simply adding them up, or only take the larger one?

Comment: You have to first calculate the stress tensors associated with your two applied forces, and then add the stress tensors together to get the total stress tensor. You can then use that tensor to calculate the maximum shear stress in the object.

Comment: Thank you, Samuel.

Comment: Thank you, Samuel. I don't know how exactly to calculate the stress tensors. Say I have a 100 lbs axial force, the socket is 4 ft. diameter and 5 ft long, if I am considering the side friction between the socket and rock, the the stress would  be total force divided by socket side area: P/(pi)DL=100/3.14/4/5=1.59 lb/ft^2. that's my side friction stress. When I am having a torsional stress in radial direction at the same time, what is the correct way to combine these two??Theoretically, when two shear stresses acting on one plane, tau(xy) and tau(xz), what is the correct way to combine them

Comment: Duplicated on engineering see https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/28208/10902

Comment: These shear stresses components are on a surface of constant radius in cylindrical coordinates.  One of the shear stress components is in the axial z direction and the other is in the circumferential $\theta$ direction.  The total shear stress  vector is the vector sum of these two components.

Comment: thank you, Chet Miller